# Bose-Einstein phase transition and average number of part in state l

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

The explanation I have trouble understanding is this: The average number of particles $<n_l>$ on state $l$ is

$$<n_l>=\frac{z}{e^{\beta \epsilon_l}-z}$$

where $z=e^{\beta \mu '}$ is the fugacity. So when the system is in the state defined by the quantum numbers $l_x,l_y$ and $l_z=0$ then $\epsilon_l=0$ and $<n_l>$ goes to infinity as $z \rightarrow 1$. This characterizes phase transition.

I get the math but I don't understand the rest. How can an *average number of particles in a specific state* ever be larger than N itself? Is this a semantics problem, just an unhappy name for this quantity? Was N approximated as very large at some point and I missed it?

Comment: That exponential in the demoninator goes to 1 too, not zero.

Comment: My mistake, I'll delete the misleading comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement that $z\to 1$ (i.e. $\mu\to 0$) already requires the limit $N\to \infty$. If $N$ is finite, the chemical potential tends to a small but finite value at the transition temperature. This ensures that the occupation of the ground state is $\langle n_0\rangle \lesssim N$.